# Django background task is locked when there are too many task at the same time

Tags: python, django

On my server when the user upload multiple files, the python code will be run to process it.

I can upload 100 files successfully, But if the files is over than that the task will be lock(I look in Django Admin page, It said "Locked by pid running") and no more files can be process.

Here is the code

```
@background(schedule=datetime.timedelta(seconds=1))
def upload_file():
   .
   .
   .
```

But If I comment the `@background` line out, 
The problem will not occur.

How can I make Django Background Task work in this situation?

@background is a decorator that turn any python function into the task. It was one of Django's package (django-background-tasks.readthedocs.io/en/latest)

Comment: Please add enough code, so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: That looks like a problem with that particular package.  You should try [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org) instead.

Comment: There are too many reasons you could get this behaviour to make it possible to answer your question without __much__ more informations. It could be an issue in your own code, it could be an issue with your setup, it could be an issue with the system's limits on opened files or other resources, etc etc etc. I strongly suggest you check the project's issue tracker and eventually submit your issue there - but the maintainers will very certainly ask for a [mcve].

Comment: @CalebGoodman celery has issues too and is not the lightest async task queue when it comes to bot setup and administration, and let's not talk about debugging. I would only recommand it for projects that really need all the power and features of a full AMQP stack.

Comment: Thank you for all the suggestion and answer. I've concluded that Django background task does not perform well with on a lot of tasks. So I'll have to put the limit on the user part instead.
Also so sorry about the code, I could not provide any more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a cheat code for example you know your file will never exceed 300 You can say in your settings

```
BACKGROUND_TASK_ASYNC_THREADS = 300
```

Or any number you like, just make sure it is your upper limit

Answer (score -1):

your question is vague, what is the code for @background decorator

Comment: @background is a decorator that turn any python function into the task.
It was one of Django's package (https://django-background-tasks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: What database you are using?

Comment: @EswarkumarEshu answers are for __answering__ a question. If you have questions, this is what comments are for.

Answer (score -1):

Django does not support the parallelization and it is synchronous language so until one task is not finished it will not start the second one. Please give some more code.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I know all these things but I am only telling what could happen in this case.